# Error during deploy - Uncaught TypeError: Invalid Version, during wrangler deploy worker on Сloudflare Node.js application

Tags: node.js, deployment, cloudflare-workers

The project is written on Node.js v18.11 with all the necessary dependencies installed in the package.json file, there is a wrangler.toml file in the root of this project.
The project uses the npm “Imap-simple” module.

When I type the “wrangler deploy” command in the terminal, I get an error:

```
⛅️ wrangler 3.1.2
------------------

Total Upload: 2309.32 KiB / gzip: 610.66 KiB

X [ERROR] A request to the Cloudflare API (/accounts/101010101001010101010010101010101abc/workers/scripts/parsit) failed.

  Uncaught TypeError: Invalid Version:
    at worker.js:4918:17 in SemVer
    at worker.js:5128:16 in compare5
    at worker.js:5168:16 in gte
    at worker.js:5629:18 in node_modules/utf7/utf7.js
    at worker.js:13:52 in __require
    at worker.js:11282:18 in node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js
    at worker.js:13:52 in __require
    at worker.js:16840:18 in node_modules/imap-simple/lib/imapSimple.js
    at worker.js:13:52 in __require
    at worker.js:17261:24 in node_modules/imap-simple/index.js
   [code: 10021]
```

// My wrangler.toml file

```
name = "app"
main = "src/main.ts"
tsconfig = "tsconfig.json"
account_id = "12123216321632163721636217361"
node_compat = true
compatibility_date = "2023-06-24"
workers_dev = false

[triggers]
crons = [ "55 */2 * * *" ] # * * * * * = run every minute
```

// My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "node": "18.11.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/imapflow": "^1.0.11",
    "@types/mailparser": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/xlsx": "^0.0.35",
    "imap-simple": "^5.1.0",
    "langchain": "^0.0.84",
    "mailparser": "^3.6.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "xlsx": "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.19.2/xlsx-0.19.2.tgz"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "29.2.4",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "29.3.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

To fix this error, I tried to do the following steps:

- In the .toml file added the variable NODE_VERSION = "11/18".
- On UI Clodeflare, I tried to manually create a Worker and set NODE_VERSION 11/18/18 in its Settings -> Environment Variables, and then execute the deploy command.
- At the bottom of the package.json file, change the node from "engines": { "node": ">=16.0.0" } to "engines": { "node": ">=18.11" }.
- In the root of the project, create a .node-version file with the node version 11/18.
- I made an explicit build of the worker.js project and looked in it exactly where “util.promisify” is called and under what conditions. I see that the “util.promisify” call is related to the “ImapFlow” module.
- Changed the local version of the node on my laptop using nvm to 18.15.0, 18.16.1., 19.0.0, 20.3.1.
- I looked at this link how to correctly name the NODE_VERSION environment variable. As far as I understand, the default version of the node as of 07/01/2022 was https://github.com/cloudflare/pages-build-image/discussions/1